# Add Schema to Body in Firebase Rest API

Tags: firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

I have created an API using firebase function, It is a POST API which takes the body values and add them, Here is the code

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));


let myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    next();
}

app.use(myMiddleware);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let response = "Server deployed successfully ";
    res.send(response);
});

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let num1 = req.body.num1;
    let num2 = req.body.num1;

    let response = num1 + num2
    res.send(response);
});


// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.endpoints = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I send the body (number 1, and number 2) in string it is giving me a response by adding two strings, But I want to add them like numbers, How can I give schema to num1 and num2 in order to accept numbers not strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Here is how I solved :)

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));

let myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    next();
}

app.use(myMiddleware);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let response = "Server deployed successfully ";
    res.send(response);

});

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let num1 = req.body.num1;
    let num2 = req.body.num2;
    let number1 = Number(num1)
    let number2 = Number(num2)
    res.send({
        "result" : number1 + number2
    });
});





// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.endpoints = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Yeah right exactly. In java you can force this more simply by putting a + in front of an expression as in: let num1= +req.body.num1 makes num1 a number.